# Material strength against kinetic energy instead of force

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy, collision, material-science

Knowing the strength of concrete you can get the mass of an object put on a concrete block is able to withstand on given area. As for a falling object, kinetic energy itself doesn't translate to force, so the force decelerating the object while collision occurs is somehow defined by material properties of the block (for simplicity, the object does not deform).

*Is it possible to calculate fall height of the object at which the concrete block will not undergo permanent deformation? And what the coefficient of restitution would be?*

Comment: “kinetic energy itself doesn't translate to force,” Where did you get that idea?

Comment: @BobD meant until force is applied to decelerate the object it doesn't, might be a poor choice of words

Comment: This is an [Impact Engineering](http://impactengineering.org/) question. You might want to take a look at Maculay's book on [Introduction to Impact Engineering](https://books.google.as/books?id=uBEACQAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false) or Majeed et al.'s paper on ["Contact force generated by impact of boulder on concrete surface"](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vsEzGIAKtTn8fFL7AaggDOASwdca2U3S/view), International Journal of Impact Engineering 132 (2019) 103324.

Answer (score 1):

> for simplicity, the object does not deform

But deformation is the key to analyzing that situation.

The block and the falling object will both deform during the impact. Without deformation, the concrete block would not exert a decelerating force on the falling object and vice versa.

Both materials will accept some amount of deformation elastically, meaning that they return to their original form. When exceeding that deformation limit, they will either keep deformed (a permanent bump) or break.

So, for the time span of the impact, you have to compute the deformations that happen (and are necessary to produce the decelerating force), and check whether the elastic-deformation limit of concrete is exceeded. But that calculation is far from trivial.